# Fixing error 000000-12301899?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I am new to ArcGIS and encountering the above error code when I'm attempting to extract data from a series of rasters.  Here's some more information:

The process: I overlaid a shapefile containing a number of coordinate points on top of a series of rasters that are tif files.  I didn't modify them because the coordinate system is the same (NAD83).  I did not apply a projection to the shapefile, but the rasters automatically have a projection applied (USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic USGS Version). I'm not quite sure if this is being projected on the fly, because in ArcCatalog, it also has the projection applied.  I then attempted to extract the data from these points using the "Multi values to point" tool.

The issue:  Every time I try to extract the data, I get an error that simply says "Extract multi values to point [000000-12301899]".  I attempted to change the rasters from tif to grid files, and that didn't help either (it executed, but the resulting attribute table had no values).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it's a coordinate transformation issue. Try projecting the points to the same spatial reference as the rasters before processing.

Comment: Check environment extent settings

Comment: Thank you! Changing the environment extent settings worked

Comment: @JBraff Could you add a bit of detail as to what you changed in the environment settings, and post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

FelixIP's solution seemed to work for me.  Here's what I did:

Go to geoprocessing --> environments

I then changed my Workspace (for some reason it was set to another ArcGIS folder that came with a GIS textbook I purchased.  This seems to be the likely culprit to me), Output Coordinates (I doubt this had anything to do with it, as both coordinate systems were the same in ArcCatalog, but I set it as NAD83 anyways), and Processing Extent (I set the range to 'Same as Display'.  It's possible that the rasters I'm using were multipart, though I did not verify this).

(Note:  I used this video for reference...https://www.coursera.org/learn/gis/lecture/SFlEk/setting-environment-variables)

Answer (score -1):

I solve this by closing the program, and restarting my computer. Nothing else seemed to work for me.