# Extract Multivalues to Points giving Error [000000_12301899]?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I am trying to run Extract Multivalues to Points in ArcMap 10.6 but I am getting an error code 000000_12301899. Below is a screenshot from the Results dialogue.

[image: Results]

Also here are the inputs. The DEM is in Albers_Conical_Equal_Area projection whilst the feature class is in NAD_1983_California_Teale_Albers.

[image: Inputs]

Does anyone have any advice on resolving this issue?

Comment: changing the environment may be solve the issue : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232272/fixing-error-000000-12301899

Comment: Project the points to the same SRS as the DEM, there is bound to be a coorinate transformation between NAD83 and *whatever datum your generic Albers has* so it's having a problem transforming during execution. If the input points have, or you want to add, a unique ID field and calculate to the FID/OID of each feature *before* projecting then you can then join the output points table to your input points using Join Field https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000 and the input points have the output fields and their geometry remains unmodified.

Comment: `Extract Multivalues to Points` requires many input rasters with one input point vector file. However, I see only one raster, in this case you need to use `Extract Values to Points` which uses only one raster file.